# Formula in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, lookup, gs-vlookup

I have a complex google sheets which has so many interlinked calculations,In 2 columns the values are not appearing now.So i'm in a process to find the root cause.

below is the formula in the 2 columns P & O.

Can anyone please let me understand what the below formula is and ho it works?

```
=IF(IsError(IFS($E:$E = "Product","")),if($B:$B = "SKU","RFC 2m avg",""),if(isNumber(Index(DATA,$G:$G,5)),Index(DATA,$G:$G,5),0))

=IF(ISERROR(IFS($E:$E = "Product","")),IF($B:$B = "SKU","RFC current month",""),Index('Products DATA'!$S:$S,MATCH($B4,'Products DATA'!$B:$B,0)))
```

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: These look like Excel formulae?